# Closing several but not all activities in android without refresh

Tags: android

How can I close several activities running above (but not all) without refreshing targeting (already running) activity?

Example: I have running activities: 1 2 3 4 5 and I would like to close from activity 5 also activities 3 and 4. This should give me activity 2, but I don'n want this activity 2 to be refreshed becausse it is scrollable list, and I want it to stay at the same position as it was when I clicked it. In this case, I want something, what would do the same job as if you clicked three times back button.

thx

Comment: You'll need to familiarize your self with the lifecycle of an Activity in Android. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I read it many times, but still can't see solution to my problem